# can't run Ext JS Kitchen Sink example

Tags: extjs6.5.1

Je suis nouveau sur extjJS6 and i try to run examples, i have a problem to run this treeMap https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/#d3-view-treemap, i put all code (Model, View, controller) in one js file, is that can cause an error? When i run i don't find exceptions but there are two message in my console:

- GET http://localhost/Ext/app/ViewController.js?_dc=20170104130840 net::ERR_ABORTED
- GET http://localhost/Ext/d3/hierarchy/TreeMap.js?_dc=20170104130840 net::ERR_ABORTED

Someone had test this example?

Comment: If the code was separated into model view and controller is not to put everything in a single file ... When using a framework it has an architecture respected.

Comment: No, wen can use model view controller in the same js file, there are a lot of examples that show what i said, but i can't run this example

Comment: I'm sure you need to make changes before putting them on a single file as they are written, it will not work ... Your error messages are clearly due to coding errors it looks for `TreeMap.js` and `ViewController.js` files except that if you put everything in a file you had to do an error somewhere. The best thing to do is either post a Sencha Fiddle link or put the code of your famous file it will already be clearer .

Comment: This my example in sencha fiddle.
- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dpg
I understand what you said but i can't find solution to correct these errors.
Thank you